# Cause for bad network conditions

Tags: networking, internet-connection

I am trying to diagnose the cause for bad network conditions. The speed of my connection seems fine, but some websites aren't loading properly (around 50% of them don't load at all.) I tried downloading a ~2gb torrent file, and it downloaded it without problem, I also played some online games to test the latency and bad conditions there, and they worked perfectly fine (never had high latency, and never lost the connection to the server.)

The "bad network conditions" means lots of lost packets, most websites not loading at all and taking ages to load (even popular sites like facebook.com or twitter.com).

I tried changing the DNS, tried different browsers in at least 4 different computers and mobile phones, and still I have really bad network conditions on all of them. Doing a `ping -t facebook.com` in 5 minutes, gives me 13% of packets lost.

My ISP is crap and they probably won't do anything. So I wanted to ask what would be the most probable causes for this to happen, so I can try to fix it myself without recurring to the awful bureaucracy my ISP has.

Thanks.

Comment: There are hundreds of different reasons for "bad network conditions" can you narrow down your question?  If you are losing packets its more then likely not something you will have control to fix.

Comment: The problem with torrent and games in testing packet loss is that neither of these are particularly sensitive to it.  Torrents will keep trying till they get everything, and online games have an expectation of packet loss and cater for it.  What type of connection do you have?

Comment: What's a traceroute should?  Can you tell where the packets are being dropped?

Comment: @Paul I re-read my question and fixed it. I am from Argentina and I have Telecom. I live in a rural area, so this is the only ISP we have, so I can't change it.

Comment: @ern http://pastie.org/8677412

Comment: Like you said ur ISP sucks and you are in rural Argentina.  You might not be able to do too much.  Any possibility you could try another router?  There is always a possibility (especially if ur ISP provided the router) that the router is the issue.  Also, are you connecting via wifi or wired Ethernet?

Comment: @Richie086 Both. And I might try another router soon.

Comment: I have had good luck with trendnet routers myself, but your mileage may vary.  Only router I've encountered that just works right out of the box and does not require to be rebooted frequently.  I am in no way affiliated with trendnet, just my personal experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your ISP (and/or their upstreams) suffer from overloaded peering and transit links. There's not much you can do that's likely to be worth doing. One thing you could do is find a VPN endpoint in Miami that has good connectivity to your ISP and use that to reach things that your ISP has poor connectivity to.

Comment: To clarify this, the asterisks in the traceroute are the key here.  If this was an issue with the router on your end, you wouldn't see the asterisks.